# converting a variable length lists into dict with some filters

Tags: python

#I have these two lists and i want to convert these lists such that it shows the following output :

```
l=['SDL-A-19.0.0-1-WX-ExP.tar','SDL-B-19.0.0-1-WX-ExP.tar','SDL-C-19.0.0-1-WX-ExP.tar','ReadMe']

s=['version','name']
```

#required output :

```
{"version": "19.0.0-1", "name": "A"}, {"version": "19.0.0-1", "name": "B"}, 
{"version": "19.0.0-1", "name": "C"}
```

Kindly suggest some solutions

Comment: Please update the question to show what you’ve tried/researched so far.

Comment: Use `split()` to split the name into components separated by `-`. Then extract the appropriate elements of those lists and create the dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a regex to match the different names those files can take. Based on the example you've provided, you could probably do something along the lines of:

```
import re 
out = []
for s in l:
    try:
        pat = r'^[A-Z]{3}-(?P<name>[A-Z])-(?P<version>(?:\d+\.){2}\d+-\d+).*?'
        match= re.search(pat, s)
        out.append({'version':match.group('version'), 'name':match.group('name')})
    except AttributeError:
        pass

print(out)
[{'vesion': '19.0.0-1', 'name': 'A'}, {'vesion': '19.0.0-1', 'name': 'B'}, 
 {'vesion': '19.0.0-1', 'name': 'C'}]
```

Though you might need to tweak it a little depending on the actual file names you might have. See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/MsBXi9/3) for the above cases.

Comment: Changed the regex acc to my need . Worked like a charm . Thank you so much :)

Comment: Excellent answer, +1.  Perhaps use named capture groups?

Comment: Thanks @S3DEV Nice suggestion, fitted in :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below but this has the following assumptions.
The last element of l is always "Readme" and should be ignored.
The positions of the version and name in l are consistent.

```
b=[]
for i in range(len(l)-1):
    a ={}
    a[s[0]] = l[i][6:14]
    a[s[1]] = l[i][4]
    b.append(a)
# b is your final list of dictionaries
print(b)
```

Comment: What about a version of 19.0.10?